# How many server licenses do I need for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, licensing

The licensing for SharePoint 2013 is a bit confusing, but I think I understand most of it.

All of our users are internal, so I need CALs for them. We want to use enterprise features, so I need to add an additional Enterprise CAL for each user.

Microsoft's site states that a server license is required for each server running an instance of SharePoint. Our farm configuration consists of 2 Web Front End (WFE) servers, 3 Application servers, 2 Index servers, and potentially 1 crawling server.

My question is, do all 7/8 servers require a SharePoint 2013 server license? Do just the WFEs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Server/CAL licensing model requires both a server license for each copy of the server software a customer installs and uses and CALs for the users (or devices) that 
access that software."

What that means you need a license for all the server where Software(SharePoint) is running, so in other words, all WFE, App, Indes and Crawl servers. you need 7/8 server license.

then each user covered by individual cal, in case of enterprise Cal, if you get ent call for user then no need standard call for that user because Enterprise cal covered the standard.

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/SharepointServer2013.aspx

Comment: This is the right answer.  I just recently had to do this myself for my company.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, according to Microsoft, SharePoint Enterprise CAL is additive: To access the Enterprise edition features of SharePoint, a person/device must have both the SharePoint Standard CAL and the SharePoint Enterprise CAL. (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview-collaboration-software-FX103789438.aspx)

Comment: the reason is with standard you cannot get the enterprise edition...so they mentioned device/person

Comment: I understand that enterprise has features that standard does not have. But Microsoft's language about the standard and enterprise CAL licenses being additive is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: I am telling you what we have right now, but you can check MSFT rep further about it.